# Laravel - Conditional where clauses

Tags: laravel, eloquent

net dev working in Laravel and having a great time wrapping my head around eloquent. I need someone to point out where I am going wrong here in this sample query. So when this executes I'm not getting any of the where clauses outside of the left join even though the $request is equal to what I'm checking against. Would really appreciate some "head" smacking on this one as I'm sure it's something stupidly obvious.

```
public function get_courses_by_category_id(Request $request,$category_id)
{
    $per_page = Helper::per_page();
     $query = Course::select('courses.id','courses.slug','courses.title','courses.author','courses.price','courses.free','courses.upsell','courses.image','courses.avg_ratings','courses.total_reviews')
        ->leftJoin('course_categories', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_categories.course_id')
        ->when($request->input('rating') === true, function($query, $request){
            $query->where('courses.avg_ratings', '>=', $request->rating);
        })
        ->when($request->input('price') === 'all', function($query)
            {
                $query->where('price');
            })
            ->when($request->input('price') === '250', function($query){
                $query->where(`courses.price`, `<= || is`, 249.99, `price`, null);
            })
            ->when($request->input('price') === '500', function($query){
                $query->where(`courses.price`, `>= || <=`, 250.00, `price`, 499.99);
            })
            ->when($request->input('price') === '1000', function($query){
                $query->where(`courses.price`, `>= || <=`, 500.00, `price`, 999.99);
            })
            ->when($request->input('price') === '1001', function($query){
                $query->where(`courses.price`, `>=`, 1000.00);
            });

    $courses = $query->orderBy('courses.created_at','DESC')->paginate($per_page);

    if($courses && $courses->count()){
        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'courses'=>$courses]);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['status'=>false,'courses'=>[]]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help

```
$query = Course::select('courses.id','courses.slug','courses.title','courses.author','courses.price','courses.free','courses.upsell','courses.image','courses.avg_ratings','courses.total_reviews')
        ->leftJoin('course_categories', 'courses.id', '=', 'course_categories.course_id')
        ->when($request->input('rating') === true, function($query, $request){
            $query->where('courses.avg_ratings', '>=', $request->rating);
        })
        ->when($request->input('price') !== 'all', function($query) {
            $query->when($request->input('price') === '250', function($query){
                $query->orWhere('courses.price', '<=', 249.99);
            })
            ->when($request->input('price') === '500', function($query){
                $query->orWhereBetween('courses.price', [250.00, 499.99]);
            })
            ->when($request->input('price') === '1000', function($query){
                $query->orWhereBetween('courses.price', [500.00, 999.99]);
            })
            ->when($request->input('price') === '1001', function($query){
                $query->where('courses.price', '>=', 1000.00);
            });
        });
```

Comment: This seems to have the same exact issue as my query above. Not entirely certain why either.

Comment: Well I've just provide you the solution of your question. Unless you provide me with more details of your problem